# unable to correctly load font-awsome icons in navbar using link_to method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icons

Im trying to add font-awsome icons to my (link_to) links within a simple navbar i created, however im not sure as to how to correctly write the code using ruby syntax as apposed to the html. This is the code I would like to add the icons to:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
         <li><%= link_to "Main", root_path %></li>
         <li><%= link_to "Employee Profile", profile_path %>
                <ul>
                    <li><%= link_to "Tasks / Activities", "#" %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Vacations", "#" %></li>
                </ul>
         </li>
         <li><%= link_to "Projects", projects_path %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Projects Documents", project_docs_path %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Search", search_path %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Reports", reports_path %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "Feedback", feedback_path %></li>
    </ul>
```

I would like each one of my (link_to) tags to have its own font-awsome icon. As an exmample, could you provide me with the correct syntax to include the following icon to my "Employee Profile" section:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

Here is a link to the icon's page:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/user/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link_to tag can be used as a 'block'. You can use in this way to include font-awesome in link_to

```
<%= link_to profile_path do %>
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>Employee Profile
<% end %>
```